# Installing Flashdevelop dark color scheme for using with Haxe?

Tags: editor, flashdevelop, haxe

I downloaded bunch of nice looking FD schemes for AS3. It seems like there are no nice ready made Haxe schemes for FD.  As I understand one can use the As3 scheme in FD for Haxe but I am so far unable to achieve it and searching did not bring any usable result.

As far as I can tell I am able to install the As3 colors fine then I rename to Haxe.xml but that does not work for me :(

I would appreciate if a SO user  help me out with this. I am using FD 4.2.4

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The FlashDevelop theme I created (and have been tweaking over the years) include dark colors for Haxe:
http://tronster.com/code/fd/FlashDevelop-TronsterColors_v4.zip

Answer (score 0):

When you go to `FlashDevelop > Tools > Syntax coloring` you can edit the colors. These are categorized per coding language.

There are differences between Haxe and AS3, that makes it not possible to copy/paste/rename. However, when you take a look at the names, there are similarities. Just copy/paste those you find in the AS3 version to the haxe theme and it kinda looks the same.

Share the Haxe version of the theme with the original creator to make the web a bit more complete.